# Minus each value of data

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have sort of data,

```
A = [2 4 6 8 10]

B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

How to write program that can subtracts each value of A from all values of B.

To better understand,

Take `A = 2`, subtract from all `B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`,
then take `A = 4`, subtract from all `B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`
and so on...

Comment: Do you want `B-2-4-6-8-10` or a new matrix with `B-2`,`B-4`,...,`B-10` as rows?

Comment: I want new matrix with B-2, B-4, B-6, B-8 and B-10

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a new array `C` that contains, in row `i` the result of `B-A(i)`, you use `bsxfun`:

```
A = [2 4 6 8 10];

B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

C = bsxfun(@minus,B,A') %'# 
C =
    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6
    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4
    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -9    -8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0
```

If you want to create a new array `C` that contains the result of `B-A(1)-A(2)-...`, you write

```
C = B-sum(A)

C =
   -29   -28   -27   -26   -25   -24   -23   -22   -21   -20
```

Comment: +1 For appropriate use of BSXFUN.  It's an underutilized function.